# Is it possible to add more options to the interval of poormanscron in drupal?

Tags: cron, drupal-6

Basically I need to run cron more frequently than every hour, but the options in Site Information only go as low as 1 hour. Is there anyway to bypass this or add more options to have cron automatically run say every 30 minutes instead?

I've tried adding more to the array in the below function withing the poormanscron module file but they didn't seem to take anyway.

```
function poormanscron_form_system_site_information_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) 
    {
      $form['cron_safe_threshold'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Automatically run cron'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('cron_safe_threshold', 10800),
        '#options' => array(0 => t('Never')) + drupal_map_assoc(array(1800, 3600, 10800, 21600, 43200, 86400, 604800), 'format_interval'),
        '#description' => t('When enabled, the site will check whether cron has been run in the configured interval and automatically run it upon the next page request. For more information visit the <a href="@status-report-url">status report page</a>.', array('@status-report-url' => url('admin/reports/status'))),
      );
      $form['buttons'] += array('#weight' => 100);
      array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'poormanscron_site_information_settings_submit');
    }
```

Comment: When you added values to that array, did they show up under the Site Information section, but just not actually run at that interval? Or did they not show up in the Site Information section at all?

Comment: They didn't show up at all. In a desperate attempt to understand how it was working I even tried over-writing the original ones and they still didn't take effect.

Comment: They should show up after altering that. Make sure you're saving the module file in the correct location and try flushing your site's cache.

Comment: Ok so yeah clearing the cache worked on the copy site but not the main site. So clearly there must be some conflict on the main site :/ So the problem is elsewhere. Thanks very much for your help though!

Comment: No problem. And you're sure you updated the module file on both the copy site and the main site?

Comment: Yep. The only difference there is between the main and the copy, is that I recently updated all the core and module files on the copy to iron out problems before doing it on the live. So that's the only difference between them at the moment. Both sites have poormanscron fully updated but maybe the fact that the rest of the site is not could be reacting differently to the changes I'm making.